# Two of my common components that I'm importing with index.js don't fire

Tags: react-native

I'm doing [this course](https://www.udemy.com/course-dashboard-redirect/?course_id=959700) at Udemy.    Files: https://github.com/StephenGrider/ReactNativeReduxCasts/tree/master/auth

The issue I'm having is with importing common components.  It's only for 2 of the common components--the rest work fine. Card, CardSection, Header, Input.

When I try to import the Button or Spinner, they won't fire. But if I use the basic functionality (putting the TouchableOpacity or ActivityIndicator in the file directly and do all the styling THERE), they work fine.

Here's the file structure:
[image]

Here's /components/common/index.js

```
export * from './Header';
export * from './Input';
export * from './Card';
export * from './CardSection';
export * from './Button';
export * from './Spinner';
```

Here's Button.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const Button = ({ propOnPress, children }) => {
    const { buttonStyle, textStyle } = styles;
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={propOnPress} style={buttonStyle}>
            <Text style={textStyle}>
                {children}
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}

const styles = {
    textStyle: {
        alignSelf: 'center',
        color: '#fff',//'#007aff',
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: '600',
        paddingTop: 10,
        paddingBottom: 10
    },
    buttonStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        backgroundColor: '#007aff', //'#fff',
        borderRadius: 5,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#007aff',
        marginLeft: 5,
        marginRight: 5,
    }
}

export { Button };
```

Here's Spinner.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

const Spinner = ({ size }) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.spinnerStyle}>
            <ActivityIndicator size={size || 'large'} />
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = {
    spinnerStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
}

export { Spinner }
```

Here's where I import them in LoginForm.js

```
import { Card, CardSection, Button, Spinner, Input } from './common';
```

And where they're used in the code in LoginForm.js

```
renderButton() {
    //console.log('render button');
    if (this.state.loading) {
        console.log('returning the spinner');
        return <Spinner animating={this.state.loading} size="small" />;
    }

    console.log('gonna return a button');
    return(
        <Button onPress={this.onYouPressedIt.bind(this)}>Log in</Button>
    );
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Issues I see with the `Button.js` file

1. Property `onPress` doesn't exist. You created a property called `propOnPress`

So, your Button component should be used like this

```
<Button propOnPress={}>...</Button>
```

Issues I see with the `Spinner.js` file

1. Property `animating` doesn't exist on the component. The only properties you created is `size`.

Solution would be to simply add an `animating` property to your `Spinner` component.

Component would end up looking like this

```
const Spinner = ({ animating, size }) => {
    return (
        { 
            animating ? (
                <View style={styles.spinnerStyle}>
                    <ActivityIndicator size={size || 'large'} />
                </View>
            ) : null
        }
    )
}
```

I assume the `animating` property is a boolean which if false then you don't want to display the activity indicator which is why I added the ternary operator.

Comment: I implemented the changes for Button and it worked GREAT!  However, I'm getting an error for Spinner: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got undefined.

Comment: That error message usually means a component is being imported incorrectly or a component isn't being exported correctly. I don't see that issue with the code above though. Does that last log statement fire logging `returning the spinner` just before the spinner tries to render?

Comment: I can import the Spinner if I do it in the traditional way, with "export default Spinner;" at the bottom of Spinner.js and "import Spinner from './components/common/Spinner';" in LoginForm.js.  But if I change the export statement to "export { Spinner };" in Spinner.js, add "export * from './Spinner';" to /common/index.js, and add , Spinner to the "import { Card, CardSection, Button, Spinner, Input } from './common';" statement in LoginForm.js, THAT's when I get the error

Comment: and yes, to answer your question, it outputs "returning the spinner" when i'm doing everything the traditional way

Comment: Hmmm, I don't see any issues with the way you're going about it with the named exports/imports. It shouldn't matter but have you tried clearing the cache on metro?